# FreeBSD Media Subtypes

Tags: freebsd

How do I find a list of the supported media subtypes in FreeBSD? Is there a list or a man page somewhere?

Context: I am trying to change the speed of one of my network interfaces using the command

```
ifconfig lagg1 media <10G media type> mediaopt full-duplex
```

When I try

```
ifconfig lagg1 media 10gbaset mediaopt full-duplex
```

I get the error

```
ifconfig: unknown media subtype: 10gbaset
```

Comment: Please comment when downvoting so I know what to improve about my question.

Comment: Is it same what you're looking for? https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/sys/net/if_media.h#L394

Comment: Yes! That's exactly it! Thank you! Feel free to write that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Probably because it has little to do with programming. One option is http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it same what you're looking for? 
[github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/sys/net/if_media.h#L394](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/sys/net/if_media.h#L394)

Answer (score 1):

Use "ifconfig -m".  I'm not sure if this will work with lagg(4), though - lagg aggregates the links, I don't think it cares at all about media types.